# If $u \in V$, why does $Tu=0$ imply that $T$ is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$.

Let $u=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$ for $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{F}$

And define $T: V \to Mat(n,1,F)$

by $Tv=M(v)$, where $M(v)$ is the matrix of $v \in V$ wrt the basis (v_1,...,v_n).

If $Tu=0$, why is it that $a_1=...=a_n=0$, implies $u=0$, which implies that $T$ is injective?

How is it that the coefficients are zero and why does that mean u=0 and how is it that T becomes injective? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "$M(v)$ is the matrix of $v\in V$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your statement. The correct one is **$T$ is injective iff ker($T$)$ = 0$**. If $T$ is linear, clearly $T(0) = 0$. So, $T$ is injective implies ker($T) = 0$. To prove the other direction, let $T(u) = T(v)$ i.e. $T(u - v) = 0$. But, ker($T) = 0$ implies $u-v = 0$ or, $u =v$ proving $T$ is injective.

Your question is just an application of the above mentioned theorem. Since $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis, the coefficients of a vector can be zero iff the vector is zero. Hence we get that ker($T$) $= 0$ thereby proving $T$ is injective.

Comment: I made a mistake and didnt specify correct T, I updated it now. Sorry about it!

Comment: @user123276 hope I answered your question.

Comment: Hi, my confusion is how we don't know that there is some other vector in V that will also get mapped by T to 0? Meaning, why is it that 0 is the only vector that will be mapped by T to 0?

Comment: $T$ gives the matrix representation of $v$ wrt the basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ i.e if $v = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n$ then $T(v)$ will give the $n \times 1$ matrix consisting of $a_i$'s. We also know that $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ are linearly independent and hence $a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n = 0$ iff $a_1 = \dots = a_n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the other way around. If $Tu=0$ and $T$ is injective, then $u=0$. In general, you can define a linear mapping $T$ to be $Tu=0$ for all $u$, meaning that $Tu=0$ does NOT imply that $u=0$.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to specify how T was defined.